# populated JTable from another JTable

Tags: java, swing, jdbc, jtable, awt

I have two `JTable` with 4 uneditable `JTextField`s, an editable `JSpinner` and an editable button. The first table was populated by databases (fish table). The second table (cart table) should be populated by getting the value from all those `JTextField`s and `JSpinner` under two conditions:

1. If the fish id has not existed yet, insert new fish and
2. If the fish id has existed, update fish quantity with the addition of quantity.

Here is my code:

```
Vector<Object> datas = new Vector(); Vector<Object> datas2 = new Vector();
DefaultTableModel cartTableModel = (DefaultTableModel)tableCart.getModel();
DefaultTableModel listTableModel = (DefaultTableModel)tableList.getModel();
long subtotal = Integer.parseInt(tFishPrice.getText()) * qty;
datas.add(tFishId.getText());
datas.add(tFishName.getText());
datas.add(tFishType.getText());
datas.add(tFishPrice.getText());                
datas.add(qty);
datas.add(subtotal);
int rowsList = listTableModel.getRowCount();
int rowsCart = tableCart.getRowCount();

String idList = tableList.getValueAt(tableList.getSelectedRow(), 0).toString();
if(cartTableModel.getDataVector().isEmpty()){
    int oldQty = Integer.parseInt(tableList.getValueAt(tableList.getSelectedRow(), 4).toString());
    listTableModel.setValueAt((oldQty-qty), tableList.getSelectedRow(), 4);
    cartTableModel.addRow(datas);
}else{
    int index = 0;
    while( index<rowsCart){
        String idCart = cartTableModel.getValueAt(index, 0).toString();
        if(idCart.equals(tFishId.getText())){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "samaaa");
            int oldQtyCart = Integer.parseInt(cartTableModel.getValueAt(index, 4).toString());
            int oldPriceCart = Integer.parseInt(cartTableModel.getValueAt(index, 5).toString());
            int newQtyCart = oldQtyCart + qty;
            long newTotal = oldPriceCart*newQtyCart;
            cartTableModel.setValueAt(newQtyCart, index, 4);
            cartTableModel.setValueAt(newTotal, index, 5);      
            int oldQty = Integer.parseInt(tableList.getValueAt(tableList.getSelectedRow(), 4).toString());
            int y;
            for(y = 0; y < rowsList; y++){
                String id = tableList.getValueAt(y, 0).toString();
                if(id.equals(idCart)){
                    int oldqty = Integer.parseInt(listTableModel.getValueAt(y, 4).toString());
                    listTableModel.setValueAt(oldqty-qty, y, 4);
                    break;
                }
            }                            
        }else{
            String index2 =cartTableModel.getValueAt(index, 0).toString();
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, index2);
            if(!index2.equals(tFishId.getText())){
                cartTableModel.addRow(datas);
                break;
            }
```

I ended up adding a new item in second table, even though I added the same id.
I appreciate any solution, whether it's fixing my code or providing a different solution. thx

Comment: Don't use the back button when editing your question. Click on the "edit" link, otherwise edits from others will be lost.

Comment: *I end up adding new item in second table,even i added same id* - well debug you code to find out why you do this. Obviously one of your if conditions is wrong. Use a debugger to step through the code to see where it is going wrong, or add debug code to help follow the logic flow. We can't help because we don't have access to your data or the application.

Comment: i edited on the link